# What does the phrase "Shop the edit" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have seen this phrase used in several fashion ads and on clothing sites (mostly women's). I am assuming it is AME, but I do not know. Here are some sites that I see the phrase being used:

- [Neiman Marcus](https://www.neimanmarcus.com/c/new-now-shop-the-edit-cat84710765)
- [Bloomingdale's](https://www.bloomingdales.com/shop/fashion-lookbooks-videos-style-guide/shop-the-edit?id=1041459)

Perhaps "edit" means "edition"? I have no idea. Fashionistas, answer my call! :)

Comment: There's a whole separate question to be asked about the (growing?) use of 'shop' in contexts where I personally would use 'shop *for*', a usage which I feel is relatively recent; but, you know, recency illusion...

Comment: It would be helpful to know which online dictionaries you have checked for the appropriate sense of 'edit', to avoid duplication of labour.

Comment: The fact that the contributors to this site, who are devoted to appreciating and analysing the quirks of the language, are puzzled by this phrase surely shows that the it can't possibly be very successful in accomplishing its purpose.

Comment: @jsw29 Maybe its users don't _want_ it to be understood by everyone…? (I assumed it was suggesting that take some textual changes and hand them in to the authorities! But then I'm probably the wrong side of the Atlantic to be in their target market.)

Comment: I assumed "shop" was really "`shop" being an abridged way of saying "Photoshop" the well-known image editor software.   Is this plausible?

Comment: "Shop the edit" simply means "Buy our new range of clothes".  There have been [complaints about abuse of language](https://www.dailyedge.ie/fashion-speak-translated-3829864-Feb2018/) in the fashion industry.

Comment: @Henry, does it really mean 'buy our new range of clothes (that could be quite an expenditure) or 'buy **something from** our new range of clothes'?

Comment: @akashm "Shop for" wouldn't be appropriate in this context.  "Edit" is not an object you are shopping for, rather a collection from which products can be purchased.  Think "shop the collection" rather than "shop for the collection".

Comment: @jsw29 Technically you are right.  I took Henry's comment to be the goal of the phrase, which is a call to action to have shoppers look at the shop's collection of clothes and buy from it, preferably as much as their wallet can oblige.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/edit)

> a range of clothes or other goods that has been chosen for a
> particular purpose, or to be worn or used at a particular time

"Edit" is used as one would use "collection", to describe a curated set of clothing. "Shop the edit" is simply combining that with a call to action (e.g., "shop the collection.") I can't find any definitive etymology for the term, but I would take it to reflect the curatorial definition of edit ("to prepare [something, such as literary material] for publication or public presentation", [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edit)) rather than as an abbreviation of "edition."

Comment: In accordance with the *OED*, you are correct: *edit* the noun comes from the verb *edit*, not the noun *edition*.

Comment: What exactly is 'a curated set of clothing'? Is that (1) a set of things that are meant to be worn together, or (2) a set of things that are offered at the same time as alternatives to each other.

Comment: @jsw29 Laurel's answer might provide you with more context. I've seen it used in several contexts. A "summer edit" might just be a brand's summer collection, whereas a "coat edit" will highlight their latest coats. It also depends if it's coming from a brand or something like a department store. The Bay had a jacket edit a couple of years ago that didn't exhaust their entire collection of jackets, but highlighted some new & noteworthy items. Some brands also seem to make it a complete editorial feature with photos, almost like a lookbook. I think it's become somewhat of a buzzword recently.

Comment: @garnerstan, so, it seems that your answer is (2).

Comment: @jsw29 Not necessarily; if it's a summer edit, for instance, some of the items would probably be advertised to be worn together.

Comment: @jsw29 'a curated set of clothing' derives from a museum or art gallery *curator* as a permanent position, then used for bringing in a individual to choose pieces for a particular exhibition, and subsequently used when an individual selects some clothes to be marketed as a set.  It may even have gone so far as to not need a named individual, and just means a selected set of clothing.

Comment: @Henry, I know very well what the ordinary, traditional meaning of *curated* is. My question, above, was very specific: whether garnesrtan, **in this answer**, meant (1) or (2) by 'a curated set of clothing'.

Answer (score 22):

The graphic from Bloomingdale's gives a hint in large letters:

[image: "Editorial" above "Our Edit"]

Based on this, I looked and found some vendors that ask you to  "shop the editorial":

- [The Latest Scoop](https://thelatestscoop.ca/collections/shop-the-editorial)
- [OAK - creative essentials](https://www.instagram.com/p/qkHoUGtAEb/)
- [Country Road](https://m.facebook.com/CountryRoad/posts/10156185393062335)
- [No Man Walks Alone](https://nomanwalksalone.com/blogs/look-books/fw21-editorial-winter-again-mayan-rajendran)

Here's a definition from a fashion site:

> Editorials are four to ten-page visual stories that showcase fashion, beauty, and lifestyle trends in magazines. — [Fashion Model Daily](http://www.fashionmodeldaily.com/what-is-editorial-modeling/)

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/words-were-watching-editorial-new-meaning) gives this relevant excerpt explaining some broader context:

> In the specific context of print advertising, editorial photography is often contrasted with advertising photography: in the former, the photographs are used to tell a story or to express a mood; in the latter, they sell a product. Since the 1990s, the word editorial has been applied as a descriptor of ads that blur the line between the two:
>
> > Developed by San Francisco's Kevin McPhee & Associates, the [magazine ad] campaign depicts world-class skiers posed informally on the slopes in Marmot gear, alongside newsy bits of copy relating the skiers' most exhilarating experiences. The copy appears in alternative typefaces, like those used on the editorial spreads of magazines that speak to younger, more adventurous readers. "We wanted the ads to look very editorial," explained David Begler, who wrote the campaign, "and we chose people who are hardcore skiers to convey the message that, with this outerwear, people can have peak experiences of their own."
> > — DNR (The Daily News Record), 9 Oct. 1995

And if you're still not convinced, here are some pages that use both *editorial* and *edit*:

- [Between — Seasons: Spring/Summer Editorial](https://infinitedefinite.com/pages/between-the-seasons-spring-summer-editorial): "In our latest Spring/Summer edit we've taken to our favourite all-season spot, Taylor's Mistake, to explore the possibilities of trans-seasonal dressing."
- [The Fall Edit](https://cargocollective.com/gramartin/The-Fall-Edit): "The editorial features a laid-back, yet elegant mix of fall basics in a way that it can appeal to ‘real’ women."
- [NobodyDenim](https://www.instagram.com/p/BoWDaPHAroA/?taken-by=nobodydenim): "EDITORIAL | @jaclynadams captures our newest edit, where Black and White meet, and explore New York City together"

Comment: Wait...so are you saying 'edit' is short for 'editorial'?

Comment: @Mitch That's what it looks like to me based on everything I included in the post.

Comment: It'd be nice to make that explicit, rather than to have to make that connection myself. eg " tldr: 'edit' seems to be an abbreviation of 'editorial' which is ... and 'shop the editorial' means to 'use the visual story in the editorial as examples of thinks to shop for' "

Comment: *Edit* the noun comes from the verb *edit*, it is not short for *editorial*. From the OED: **edit**, *n.2* Etymology: < EDIT *v.* **4**. A selection of clothes, accessories, beauty products, etc., from a particular season or collection, esp. as chosen by a fashion buyer, editor, or designer.

Comment: I actually still didn't understand after reading this post, until I read Mitch's comment; "shop" is not a verb I understand in this context.

Comment: @PatrickStevens "shop" here just means "buy" but may sound more fashionable.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I consider it probable that some enterprising marketing person used it in the sense you mention, but other enterprising marketing persons didn't understand it, and *expanded* it to editorial, mistakenly thinking it was an abbreviation for that, thus establishing the new usage in the fashion industry. The last three quotes in this answer strongly suggest such an evolution.

Comment: @SebastianRedl : See my comment on my answer. If you look at the number and nature of the search results, you will see that this is at best a case of monkey-see-monkey-do, and has little traction beyond that. No evolution revolution.

Comment: In short, being asked to "shop the edit" means being asked to buy (shop [for]) the clothes that they're advertising (in the inaptly and ineptly named "edit").

Answer (score 5):

*Shop the edit* means *go shopping at this destination offering a curated selection of stuff*.

*Shop* is a transitive verb born of the noun *shop*. *Edit* is a noun born of the verb *edit*.

From the [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required):

> **shop**, *v.<sup>1</sup>*
>  <sub>**Origin**: Formed within English, by conversion. **Etymon**: SHOP *n.*
>
> **Etymology**: < SHOP *n.*</sub>
>
> **4. b.** *transitive*. To go shopping at (a store, an online retailer, etc.); to examine goods on sale in (a shop, etc.).
> Originally *North American*.
>  <sub>[selected examples]
>  1955
>   *Albert Lea (Minnesota) Eve. Tribune* 17 Feb. 10/3 (advt.)
>   Shop the store that gives you more.
>   1974   S. MARCUS
> *Minding Store* iv. 85   One man who had shopped the entire store complained that he hadn't found what he was looking for.
>  2011
>   *Harper’s Bazaar* (U.K. ed.) July 39   From this month,
> Brits can shop the online store.</sub>

*Edit* is not a shortened version of *editorial* or *edition*; it’s a “real” noun. More from the *OED*:

> **edit**, *n.<sup>2</sup>*
>  <sub>**Origin**: Formed within English, by conversion. **Etymon**: EDIT *v.*
>
> **Etymology**: < EDIT *v.*</sub>
>
> **4.** A selection of clothes, accessories, beauty products, etc., from a particular season or collection, esp. as chosen by a fashion
> buyer, editor, or designer.
>  <sub>1993   *Elle* Oct. 190/1
>   The clothes he chose for them [*sc.* models]..represent the
> most graphically striking the new store has to offer. ‘What sets
> Barneys apart..is the incredible edit. You end up with a focused point
> of view.’
>  1999   *Independent* (Nexis) 22 Aug. (Features
> section) 8   Just swing by the store for the best edit of zebra,
> tiger, leopard and dalmatian print boots, stiletto sandals and
> under-arm bags.
>  2011   *Harper’s Bazaar* (U.K. ed.) July
> 141/1   A breathtaking array of..brands, all handpicked to form
> an exciting edit of the world’s best products.</sub>

As Merriam Webster puts it, an [edit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/edit) is an instance or result of editing.

Comment: -1 Disagree with your suggested etymology. If one derives the already-existing word "edit" from a different origin, namely "editorial", the dictionary isn't going to make a separate entry just for the alternate etymology. Laurel's numerous links that document the phrase "shop the editorial" prove the actual situation.

Comment: Your dictionary quotation and examples for transitive *shop* is for going shopping at the store, and the store being the direct object.  The usage in "shop the edit" is different, with the stuff being purchased as the direct object.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins, note that the examples in the quoted OED entry do not involve anything resembling an editorial: *edit* in them is something that is **in the store**, not in a publication of any kind. On the other hand, it is true that the examples in Laurel's answer are about what appears in the publications of some sort. Perhaps the only conclusion one can draw from all this is that this use of the term is hopelessly confused: it seems that the people writing this stuff pick up the term from others in the field, without pausing to think what it is actually supposed to stand for.

Comment: @Henry No, "the edit" means "the catalog of items that are referenced in the edit" in this case--it's a (virtual) section of the store/catalog. It might be more clear in this other common usage, "shop the sale", where "the sale" is the whole collection of items that are on sale.  (I hate this usage personally, but it's somewhat internally consistent.)

Comment: @DanielR.Collins : I didn’t suggest the etymology — I cited the *OED*. If you compare the number and the nature of search results for `"shop the edit"` and `"shop the editorial"`, you would likely surmise that the people using *shop the editorial* are simply making the same assumption that Laurel did: *Edit* is an odd noun; I’m not looking it up in the dictionary; it must be short for *editorial*; other people did it, so it must be real.

Comment: @Henry : See the definition again and apply the *etc.*: *examine goods on sale in (a shop, etc.)*. In a collection. In an edit. On aisle 5.

Comment: The OED entry 4 for 'edit' is very compelling with "A selection of clothes..." which should be enough for being 'the' answer, but even if correct it is tantalizingly missing the connection. Laurel's answer -gives- a plausible connection but there's no authority behind it. I'm -so- curious now - what gave the OED the ability to say that 'edit' is a selection of clothes?

Comment: @Mitch : From [OED terminology](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/glossary/): “The *OED* is based on quotation evidence: real examples of words in use, throughout the written record. Almost every sense and lemma of every entry includes a set of quotations showing when, where, and how it was used . . .” I don’t think the *OED* is the *be-all* or *end-all* (two of which words you will find there). But I can pretty much guarantee that its earliest example for *edit* (meaning a curated selection of stuff), in 1993, was not found on the internets but in print.

Comment: @TinfoilHat I'm not sure what point you're trying to make with respect to what I said in my comment, but my point was that outside of this question it is interesting to wonder what the provenance (the chain of meaning shown by examples) that got 'edit' the (very unexpected) meaning of 'selection of clothes'. In other words, how can you make the bald claim that "Edit is not a shortened version of editorial or edition"? You can't say that without more history. As interesting as that might be (and would be a nice addition here), for the OP you only need to cite this definition 4. It's enough.

Comment: @Mitch: This usage of "edit" has similarities (in my mind at least) to things like a song having a "radio edit": for a long song, that can be a shorter version of a longer song (the album version). Usage like "The radio edit is 2 minutes long".  A fashion company selecting some combination of their product line makes sense to me as an "edit" in that sense: an edit of their full catalogue. That could be totally separate from advertising them in an editorial feature, or it might be how the term came up; we don't know.  "Shop the edit" (browse this selection) is still barely intelligible, though.